# JTable Scoping and adding a row

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtable, defaulttablemodel

So I have a lot of experience with procedural languages and I'm trying to map it to Java.

I have code that creates a default table model using a csv file and loads the file into a JTable inside a tab. It works great. But now I want to add lines to the table and I can't figure out how to get access to the JTable to do an addrow.

```
/* Build the fight index tab from a file */

public void LoadIndexTable(String file) {

    try {    
        FileReader fin = new FileReader(file);
        DefaultTableModel imodel = createTableModel(fin, null);
        JTable itable = new JTable(imodel);
        indexpanel = new JScrollPane(itable);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

/* Add a row to the index table */

```
public void AddIndexRow() {

    itable.addRow(new Object[]{"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"});

}
```

/* Load csv files into tables with correct headers */

```
public static DefaultTableModel createTableModel(Reader in, Vector<Object> headers) 
{
    DefaultTableModel model = null;
    Scanner s = null;

    try {
        Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
        s = new Scanner(in);

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            rows.add(new Vector<Object>  (Arrays.asList(s.nextLine().split("\\s*,\\s*",-1))));
        }

        if (headers == null) {
            headers = rows.remove(0);
            model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
        } else {
            model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
        }

        return model;

        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Some where, you need to maintain a reference to the `TableModel` as a class instance variable.  This would allow the class that declares the variable to access it (from what is essentially a global concept for the instance of the class) and if required, provide it the ability to supply support methods to allow other classes to modify the model indirectly

Comment: I was trying to figure that out. The TableModel is based on a file name and the name is selected by the user. So I define it in LoadIndexTable when the file is selected. I don't think I can define the model on one file and then replace it with the selected file. I could be wrong.

Comment: I think I got it. Will post if I do.